# How to update the value of an html input without using binding in a Blazor Server application

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

There are issues with Blazorn on free typing input controls like text and text area when you use @bind or value as it is constantly communicating with the server so when typing fast into these controls it gets behind and overwrites the value on the screen as you're typing.

To get around this I removed binding and just use @oninput to get my value from the input element and do what I need to do.  However on some pages I need to be able to pre-populate the input box with a string and this doesn't seem possible.

Is there any way to turn off or intercept the call back to the server when Blazor is two-way communicating with a bound text box?

Alternatively, is there a way to update the text box value without using binding?

I'd prefer to have a solution to the first question as that would fix every textbox/area I have, however if that is not possible, I'd be happy with simply forcing a value into that box.

Comment: Can you provide a [MRE] to demonstrate your problem?  You first paragraph suggests you might have a issue with how you are configuring your bind.  I haven't seen problems reported on fast typing issues.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - there is an issue with bind, especially in production environments, localhost doesn't show it, and it is well documented.  Simply make a page with an input control and your favorite way to bind, push it into any non localhost environment, and type really fast.. you'll see it.  Also an example posted here with a bind wouldn't make sense as I'm not using one. I would be posting an input tag with an @onlick= inside it.

Comment: I didn't believe you, but as the saying goes there's no smoke without fire.  So I've just done exactly as you suggested and deployed a simple site to Azure - https://demo-sites.azurewebsites.net/.  I don't see a problem [but I may have tunnel vision].  Can you provide links to where it is *well documented*.

Comment: Also note that with a standard `InputText` component the EventCallback is only triggered on the changed event i.e. a return or when you move elsewhere.  There's no Blazor interaction taking place while you type very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to solve the first question but if you want to "update the text box value without using binding", you could use javascript Interop as below:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<input @oninput="(e)=>test(e)" />
<button @onclick="Update">Update</button>

<input id="input2"/>

<script>
    function JsUpdate(myvalue){
        document.getElementById("input2").value = myvalue;
    }
</script>

@code{
    private string myValue;
    private void test(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        myValue = e.Value.ToString();
    }
    private async Task Update()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("JsUpdate", myValue);
    }
}
```